# How do I build a custom RNN layer in Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement a custom RNN layer in Keras and I tried to follow what explained in this [link](http://benjaminbolte.com/blog/2016/keras-language-modeling.html), which basically instructs how to inherit from the existing RNN classes. However, the update equation of the hidden layer in my formulation is a bit different: `h(t) = tanh(W.x + U.h(t-1) + V.r(t) + b)` and I am a bit confused. In this equation, `r(t) = f(x, p(t))` is a function of `x`, the fixed input distributed over time, and also `p(t) = O(t-1).alpha + p(t-1)`, where `O(t)` is the Softmax output of each RNN cell.

I think after calling `super(customRNN, self).step` in the inherited `step` function, the standard `h(t)` should be overridden by my definition of `h(t)`. However I am not sure how to modify the `states` and also `get_constants` function, and whether or not I need to modify any other parts of the recurrent and simpleRNN classes in Keras.
My intuition is that the `get_constants` function only returns the dropout matrices as extra states to the step function, so I am guessing at least one state should be added for the dropout matrix of `V` in my equations.

I have just recently started using Keras and I could not find many references on custom Keras layer definition. Sorry if my question is a bit overwhelmed with a lot of parameters, I just wanted to make sure that I am not missing any point. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up doing it using pure Theano, which was pretty straightforward, though I miss the compact form of Keras.

Comment: Did you still never get an answer to this? I'm currently trying to do the same thing and I'd rather not use pure Theano.